# Deleting Bookmarks and History in iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, bookmarks, history

I have deleted all Bookmarks and Cleared History in my iPad.  However, when I'm in the address bar of Safari and type `www.p`, a Bookmark/History shows up that I cannot delete.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the iPad is not synced with other devices which might be adding those websites in history or website data again, these steps might help.

Tap on the "open-book" type icon in Safari to reveal bookmarks tap edit to remove them.

If you can delete your history, do it!

Go to Settings-> Safari-> Clear History and website data.

Make sure that the item is not in the Reading List either.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all bookmarks, history, and cache. If that still doesn't do the trick try clearing all settings.